# Colour table cells - bokeh

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I want to add colour to a row only if a row's cell's value is present in another datasource.
I mean, I have the list A, and the table B, so I want to colour the row X in B if a cell of the row contains a value from A...
I don't even know from where to start..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color rows and/or cells in a Bokeh DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996875/how-to-color-rows-and-or-cells-in-a-bokeh-datatable)

Comment: @ChesuCR nope. Those examples considers the same table. I need to compare the values of the table with the values of a separate list

Comment: Just add a column in the datasource of the datatable with the result of the comparison. Then use this value to color de cells

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much you need to do what ChesuCR mentioned in their comment. To take it one step further, see below a small bokeh application.

If you edit values in the first table, a callback will run and check each 'y' value. An additional column is needed to keep track whether the 'y' values are contained in the seperate list/data source. The value of the additional column is then used to color the cell.

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def update_included(attr, old, new):
    list_a = [float(a) for a in source_1.data['a']]
    ys = source_2.data['y']
    y_in = []
    for i, y in enumerate(ys):
        if y in list_a:
            y_in.append(1)
        else:
            y_in.append(0)
    print(ys, y_in, list_a)
    source_2.data['y_in'] = y_in

source_1 = ColumnDataSource(data={'a':[1001,1100]})

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="a", title="Criteria list")
]

data_table1 = DataTable(source=source_1, columns=columns, width=400, editable=True)


dict1 = {'x':[0]*6, 
         'y':[0,10,12,13,200,2001], 
         'y_in':[0]*6}

source_2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict1)

template="""
<div style="background:<%= 
    (function colorfromint(){
        if(y_in == 1){
            return("blue")}
        else{return("red")}
        }()) %>; 
    color: white"> 
<%= value %></div>
"""

formater =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)
columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="y",formatter=formater)
]

data_table2 = DataTable(source=source_2, columns=columns, width=400)

source_1.on_change('data', update_included)
curdoc().add_root(row(data_table1, data_table2))
```