# Vertical alignment of Bokeh DataTable cells

Tags: css, bokeh, python-3.8

I've followed the "Variant #3" example below to get conditionally colored text and boxes in my Bokeh DataTable, using Python 3.8.5 and Bokeh 2.2.1.

[How to color rows and/or cells in a Bokeh DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996875/how-to-color-rows-and-or-cells-in-a-bokeh-datatable)

However, this formatting gives me uneven vertical alignment for my columns (an issue which doesn't seem to happen in the original example).

[image: Bokeh DataTable with uneven vertical cell alignment]

Is there a way to ensure that the vertical alignment for the different columns is equal? The code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

from random import randint
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter

output_file("data_table.html")

data = dict(
    cola=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    colb=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    colc=['&#9608;' for i in range(10)])

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

template="""                
            <p style="color:<%= 
                (function colorfromint(){
                    if (1 < Math.abs(cola - colb) && Math.abs(cola - colb) < 10)
                        {return('green')}
                    else if (10 < Math.abs(cola - colb) && Math.abs(cola - colb) < 40)
                        {return('blue')}
                    else 
                        {return('red')}
                    }()) %>;"> 
                <%= value %>
            </p>
            """
formatter =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)

columns = [TableColumn(field="cola", title="CL1", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field='colb', title='CL2', formatter=formatter, width = 100),
           TableColumn(field='colc', title='CL3', formatter=formatter, width = 5)
          ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source,
                       columns=columns,
                       autosize_mode = "force_fit",
                       selectable = True,
                       sortable = True,
                       width=400,height=400)

show(Column(data_table))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `padding-top: 0px; border: 0px; line-height: 12px;` etc... to your table style. Replace `12px` with your desired row height.